# Have countries or electorates that have switched to proportional representation experienced less factional in-fighting?

Tags: democracy, measurement

In theory I would imagine proportional representation would reduce backroom factional in-fighting by both bringing disputes into the light of day (the voting booth) and allowing major factions to be the separate parties they often are.

*However, what is the evidence in countries or electorates that have switched to proportional representation ([MMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-member_proportional_representation) or otherwise) that they've had less factional in-fighting?*